# I am getting this problem every time whenever i run npm start in react

Tags: react-scripts

```
Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\ashuk\Desktop\react-scripts\bin\react-scripts.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LrdEy.png)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) it with the language and frameworks you are using.  I added [tag:react-scripts] but you should add any others as required.  Experts watch the tags they are familiar with so it's important to use technology-related tags to catch their attention. General-purpose tags like [tag:module] are not useful in that regard.  See also See [ask].

Comment: Also, please [edit] your question to include your code and errors as **text** rather than as a screenshot. On stack overflow images should not be used for textual content, see [*Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307500) and [*Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) for why. For instructions on formatting see *[How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186)*. A [mcve] showing what you have tried that did not work would maximize your chances of getting help.